# создать записи из массива

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть форма которая отправляет в контроллер данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на стороне контроллера хочу массив rol добавить в базу в виде отдельных записей,к примеру

```
id = 0, name = 12
id = 1, name = fqhgf
id = 2, name = gfhfgh
```

Контроллер

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    $inivation = Inivation::create($data);
}
```

Как реализовать ?

Comment: начните с того, чтобы картинку на текст заменить

Comment: Я специально картинку указал что наглядно было видно параметры запроса

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить отдельно поле `rol` и просто перебрать его

```
$rol = $request->input('rol');
if($rol) {
  foreach($rol as $key => $r) {
    Name::create([
      'id' => $key,
      'name' => $r
    ]);
  }
}
```